# BMO1 2008/09 Question 6 Trigonometry Problem

Tags: contest-math

6. The obtuse-angled triangle $ABC$ has sides of length $a,b$ and $c$ opposite the angles $\angle A, \angle B$ and $\angle C$ respectively. Prove that
   $$a^3 \cos A + b^3 \cos B + c^3 \cos C \lt abc.$$

No real idea what to do, so any contributions are appreciated.

Comment: Please use [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting mathematics on this site. It makes things much easier for everyone who reads your question. For instance, I assume that when you write "a3 cos A", you really mean $a^3\cos A$, but for all I know it might be $a \cdot 3\cos A$, or even $a_3 \cos A$, and there is no way for me to tell.

Comment: I saw [this page](http://www.bmoc.maths.org/home/bmo1-2009.pdf).

Comment: Ok thanks. Any ideas on the question?

Comment: use the theorem of cosine

Comment: I've tried, but not really got anywhere.

Comment: let $a$ is max,$x=a^2,y=b^2,z=c^2,x>y+z$, then it become $x^3+y^3+z^3+2xyz>\sum_{cyc} x^2y$

Comment: Aren't you using the answer in your proof though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is equivalent to
$\frac{\left(a^2-b^2-c^2\right) \left(a^2+b^2-c^2\right)
   \left(a^2-b^2+c^2\right)}{2 a b c}>0$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really see how you can't to this conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say came*

Comment: Ah I think I may know what you mean, but tell me: how do you make these factorisations. There are so many terms, is it simply a case of having seen the factorisation before?

Comment: i have solved many of such problems in our math-circle in Leipzig with my students two of them participated at the last IMO in Southafrica with a silver medall

Comment: As someone who is familiar with IMO questions then, may I ask how this question and other BMO questions (if you are familiar with those) compare.

Comment: you can ask me more questions, but i know no all answers